# PHP readfile() broken image issue while using https

Tags: php, image, https, readfile

We have developed a gallery application in PHP which displays a list of images. Earlier the gallery was hosted in Http and it was working fine. Recently we moved the code to https. There, we are facing a strange issue. Some of the images are not getting loaded (although some are loaded). Eventually, when we are using Http all are getting loaded correctly (in the same host). Please note, this problem is coming when are having multiple images. For a single image, code is working fine in https.

Sample codes are given below:

**loadImage.php**

```
<?php
$fileId = $_GET['id'];
$filePath = getFilePath($fileId);
if(file_exists($filePath) && isset($filePath)){
   $path = $filePath;
} else {    
   $path = "img/default.jpg";
}
$getInfo = getimagesize($path);
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
?>
```

**testImage.html**

```
<html>
 <img src="loadImage.php?id=1">
</html>
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Make sure certificates are valid and can get verified. [see curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Comment: Does console throws any error?

Comment: Is the posted code what delivers broken images? Also, why do you have `ob_clean()` and `flush()` without an `ob_start()` or have you removed any code from the posted `loadImage.php`?

Comment: Certificate is valid and verified. No error in console. ob_start() is there in the header (I have not added that part here). `loadImage.php` is the same I am using.

Comment: The code is still not working. This is the raw code I am using. Please help to get this resolved.